# PDO doesn't work when updating multiple rows with transactions

Tags: pdo, transactions, rows, updating

I'm gonna execute multiple rows of a table in same time with an instance of pdo.

I tried this :

```
try {
    $pdo->beginTransaction();
    $query = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE forum_config SET config_value = ? WHERE config_name = ?');
    $query->execute(array('activate_avatar', $_POST['activate_avatar']));
    $query->execute(array('activate_mp', $_POST['activate_mp']));
    $query->execute(array('activate_sign', $_POST['activate_sign']));
    $query->execute(array('allow_register', $_POST['allow_register']));
    $query->execute(array('avatar_max_height', $_POST['avatar_max_height']));
    $query->execute(array('avatar_max_size', $_POST['avatar_max_size']));
    $query->execute(array('avatar_max_width', $_POST['avatar_max_width']));
    $query->execute(array('cookies_expires', $_POST['cookies_expires']));
    $query->execute(array('domain_name', $_POST['domain_name']));
    $query->execute(array('forum_style', $_POST['forum_style']));
    $query->execute(array('post_flood_time', $_POST['post_flood_time']));
    $query->execute(array('post_max_size', $_POST['post_max_size']));
    $query->execute(array('post_max_smilies', $_POST['post_max_smilies']));
    $query->execute(array('session_time_out', $_POST['session_time_out']));
    $query->execute(array('sign_max_size', $_POST['sign_max_size']));
    $query->execute(array('site_closed_reason', $_POST['site_closed_reason']));
    $query->execute(array('site_open', $_POST['site_open']));
    $query->execute(array('topic_flood_time', $_POST['topic_flood_time']));
    $query->execute(array('topic_max_size', $_POST['topic_max_size']));
    $pdo->commit();
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    $pdo->rollback();
    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
unset($query);
```

But it doesn't do anything. What is the problem? Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work?  Are you getting an error message, or unexpected behavior?  If it's an error, please post it along with a stacktrace. If it's just unexpected behavior, please post your input and expected output, and the unexpected output.

Comment: You should be more specific. It looks like you may have your parameters backward. The `WHERE` clause is the second `?`, but your static values are listed first in the `execute()` arrays, while the dynamic inputs from `$_POST` are listed first.

Comment: You're catching an exception, but we don't see the initial PDO connection. Did you actually set `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` on it explicitly with `setAttribute()`? Otherwise PDO will error silently.

Comment: There's not error show, just a blank, like it doesn't do anything. I tried to catch error, but there's not. It really do nothing... I don't understand where is the problem

Comment: My problem is resolved because of your comments, thanks Michael.